# How do I deliver static html pages with vaadin router (client side)?

Tags: javascript, vaadin-router

[vaadin-router](https://vaadin.com/router) is a small client side javascript router. How do I deliver an arbitrary number of static html pages?

Answer (score 1):

The [demo](https://vaadin.github.io/router/vaadin-router/demo/#vaadin-router-getting-started-demos) contains an example how to add `router-ignore` as an attribute to an link

```
<a href="/users" router-ignore>Users</a>
```

and an example how to do deliver all files matching a specific pass as an special route

```
// this would be the first route in the router config:
var specialRoute = 
    {
        path: '/external/(.*)',
        action: (ctx, commands) => {
        window.location.pathname = ctx.pathname;
    }
 };
```

**So to deliver all html files via router we can use:**

```
var routeStaticHtmlFiles = 
{
    path: '(.*)\.html',
    action: (ctx, commands) => {
        window.location.pathname = ctx.pathname;
    }
}
```