# How the serve static html files with vaadin router

Tags: hilla, vaadin-router

I have te following route configuration in my hilla app

```
router.setRoutes([
  {path: '/', component: 'home-view'},
]);
```

this is works, but I need to publish some static html files. Not sure where to put the files and how to configure router to make them accessible with URL like `/myfile.html`?

already tried to put them in `/frontend` folder and add route, but does not work but creates a loop

```
{
  path: '(.*)\.html',
  action: (ctx, commands) => {
      window.location.pathname = ctx.pathname;
  }
}
```

Found it here [How do I deliver static html pages with vaadin router (client side)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62680138/how-do-i-deliver-static-html-pages-with-vaadin-router-client-side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is a Spring Boot server so any file you put inside `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources` is made available, e.g. if you create `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/myfile.html` then you can access it as http://localhost:8080/myfile.html.

If you are just loading a static HTML page there is no need to configure the router for it. For a link you can add `router-ignore` so that router will not try to intercept it, e.g. `"